# Tabular environment - text vertically positions itself by bottom of tikz picture in adjacent cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I would like to get my text (actually a matrix) to vertically center itself in its cell. Instead, it centers itself based on where the bottom of the tikz picture in the adjacent cell lies. This adds unnecessary height to a table I would like to eliminate. Is there any way to force the text column to align with the center of the tikz picture or to ignore the tikz picture entirely?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\newcommand{\pic}{
 {\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \useasboundingbox (0,.5) rectangle (3, -2);
    \draw (current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |} \hline
Initial Pic             &   Final Pic & U \\ \hline
\pic    &   \pic    & \\ \hline
\pic    &   \pic    &                   $\text{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\pic    &   that    &
                                        $\text{U} = .5 \begin{bmatrix}
                                            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
this    & that      &               $\text{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}                                           
\end{document}
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` to achieve the desired alignment as shown in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\newcommand{\pic}{
 {\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \useasboundingbox (0,.5) rectangle (3, -2);
    \draw (current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |} \hline
Initial Pic             &   Final Pic & U \\ \hline
\pic    &   \pic    & \\ \hline
\pic    &   \pic    &                   $\text{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\pic    &   that    &
                                        $\text{U} = .5 \begin{bmatrix}
                                            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
this    & that      &               $\text{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}                                           
\end{document}
```

[image]

As the border of the image now overlaps with the horizontal lines, you might want to add some extra vertical space (as done here using the `cellspace` package):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\usepackage{tikz}   
\newcommand{\pic}{
 {\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \useasboundingbox (0,.5) rectangle (3, -2);
    \draw (current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| Sc | Sc | Sc |} \hline
Initial Pic             &   Final Pic & U \\ \hline
\pic    &   \pic    & \\ \hline
\pic    &   \pic    &                   $\text{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\pic    &   that    &
                                        $\text{U} = .5 \begin{bmatrix}
                                            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
this    & that      &               $\text{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}                                           
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A fix with an optional argument for the baseline of the tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\newcommand{\pic}[1][-17pt]
 {\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,baseline=#1]
    \useasboundingbox (0,.5) rectangle (3, -2);
    \draw (current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |} \hline
Initial Pic             &   Final Pic & U \\ \hline
\pic    &   \pic    & \\ \hline
\pic    &   \pic    &                   $\text{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\pic[-25pt]    &   that    &
                                        $\text{U} = .5 \begin{bmatrix}
                                            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
this    & that      &               $\text{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                            1 & i & 1 & -i \\
                                            -i & 1 & i & 1 \\
                                            1 & -i & 1 & i \\
                                            i & 1 & -i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}                                           
\end{document}
```

[image]